# Custom method on interface jparepository

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities: Person and Car. I want to list the cars by id of Person using JpaRepository. I created bidirectional relashionship like a following  code

```
public class Person {
.
.
.
@OneToMany(mapped = "person")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Car> cars;
.
.
.
}
```

And the Car's Entity

```
public class Car {
.
.
.
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
@JsonBackReference
private Person person;
}
```

So, i implemented the JpaRepository to CarRepository the following way

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
@Query("SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.person_id = :person_id")
 public List<Car> getCarsByidPerson(@Param("person_id")long idPerson);
}
```

The field person_id exists on car's table on database but  i receive the following error message on spring-boot starts

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: person_id of: com.jpa_study.Car [SELECT c FROM com.jpa_study.Car c WHERE c.person_id = :person_id]
```

I need use join on select ? Or this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Is needed really the JOIN on QUERY. Follow the code fixed

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
@Query("SELECT c FROM Car c INNER JOIN Person p ON (Car.person.id = Person.id) WHERE p.id = :person_id")
 public List<Car> getCarsByidPerson(@Param("person_id")long idPerson);
}
```

Comment: It isn't the join it is the fact that you have now written a proper JPQL and not SQL. The query, by default, takes a JPQL and `person_id` is a SQL construct. Instead you should have written `SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.person.id = :person_id` and it would have worked as well (due to the property path `c.person.id` instead of sql colum `c.person_id`. Hibernate will deduce the join from that.